# jssor tab slider scale height for different content height

Tags: jssor

In the Jssor Slider http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html, second example, the slide content is fixed as 331px.

But the height of my contents is different, how do I scale the height?

Thanks.

Comment: hey @Peter, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Ned No luck with jssor, I switch back to jquery ui tab

Comment: too bad, I also had to switch to bxslider. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adjust value of 'height: 331px', and 'height: 300px' in the following code,
If you want to add 20px more, you can change it to '351px' and '320px'.

```
<div id="slider2_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 602px; height: 331px; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; ">

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left:0px; top: 29px; width: 600px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid gray; background-color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: what I means is the content of tab 1 is height 100px, tab 2 is height 500px and tab 3 is 1000px. When I in tab 1, how to dynamic change to 100px instead of 1000px ?

Comment: @jssor I am also facing same issue. I want to modify my slider div height as per their content. Content is dynamic, so I will need to calculate the height and will have to assign to `<div id="slides" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 620px; overflow:hidden; min-height: 3000px">` as min-height. But it's not changing. Please help me out this.